# Allowed To Read Statuses Even With Permission Denied?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I'm following a tutorial on programming with Flash / Flex and Facebook (see http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt1.html). This is a desktop app that connects to Facebook, rather than a web app.

When first testing the ability to read statuses I allowed the app to read them (obviously) when asked, so that worked just fine.

For the hell of it, I then revoked permission and when it asked me again, said Skip. It was still allowed to read them! (result object was valid, fail object was null).

So I then tried again (and it asked me again, since it still did not have permission), and this time I specifically clicked the cross to *deny* permission... and it was still able to read them!

Have I perhaps missed something? This is the code I'm using:

```
private function showStatus(): void 
{ 
    FacebookDesktop.requestExtendedPermissions(onGetStatusGranted,"read_stream"); 

} 
private function onGetStatusGranted(resultData: Object, failData: Object): void 
{ 
    FacebookDesktop.api("/me/statuses", onGotStatus); 

} 
private function onGotStatus(resultData: Object, failData: Object): void 
{ 
    if (failData != null && failData.error.code == 200) 
    {
        // User didn't allow it. 

        return ; **** Doesn't get here! **** 

    }

    if (failData == null && resultData != null && resultData.length > 0) 
        this.userStatusLabel.text = "Status: " + resultData[0].message ; **** Always gets here ***

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely encountered a bug. Statuses require `read_stream` permission, unless you are a public page.